# select item by text with jshjohnson choices

Tags: javascript, choices.js

How to realize selection of an item from choices element using [jshjohnson choices library](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices).

Code:

```
let vehicleModel = document.getElementById('vehicleModel');

let choiceProps = {
   renderChoiceLimit: -1,
   maxItemCount: -1,
   silent: false,
   removeItems: false,
   editItems: false,
   searchEnabled: true,
   searchFields: 'label',
   searchResultLimit: 6,
   itemSelectText: 'Кликните для выбора',
   classNames: {
       listSingle: 'form-control pl-3',
       containerInner: 'p-0'
   },
};

const modelChoices = new Choices(vehicleModel, choiceProps);
let models = []; // I get the values from axios to pass them as paramater
modelChoices.setChoices(models, 'value', 'label', false);
```

After I initiated choices element in another part of code i have to select a value with autofilling function

```
const fillModelWithValue = (modelName) => {
   let modelCoices = document.getElementById('vehicleModel').setChoiceByValue(modelName);
}
```

This code doesn't work. But how can I realize this functionality?